# Hide/close menu when mouse is clicked outside its focus

Tags: winapi, menu

I have a legacy code in which WIn 32 programming is done.

In here, there's a tray icon which launches a menu when right clicked on.

However, the menu persists even when clicked outside its focus area.

How do I close the menu when I mouse click in some other place?

Frameworks like Qt manage it fine enough. Do I have to keep track of the mouse pointer, capture the click and see whether it falls outside the menu area?

Code is in legacy C, and no object oriented concepts are used..so not like I can override something here.

Kindly advise, thanks.

Comment: There are many applications that don't seem to do this properly. You're not alone :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read the Remarks at the bottom of the docs for the `TrackPopupMenu` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002(v=vs.85).aspx

Specifically:

> To display a context menu for a notification icon, the current window
>   must be the foreground window before the application calls
>   TrackPopupMenu or TrackPopupMenuEx. Otherwise, the menu will not
>   disappear when the user clicks outside of the menu or the window that
>   created the menu (if it is visible). If the current window is a child
>   window, you must set the (top-level) parent window as the foreground
>   window.

Comment: So, in this case, when there's no actual application window, what handle do I pass on to the `SetForegroundWindow( HANDLE)`. The window on display behind the menu could be just about any application..

Comment: You must have a window, otherwise where do you get the message that your tray icon has been clicked?